# Node + Redis + PHP getting RealTime Issue

Tags: node.js, sockets, redis, socket.io, node-redis

I'm building a Pub/Sub Server in NodeJS + Redis + PHP, after dig in on the subject and starting building something I came across some confusion that I saw on the process.

**Example Scenario:**

- *5* users are connected to the socket through `NodeJs`correctly.
- One of them click a button to send an custom `alert` to all the connected users except him
- Php receive the the message for the alert trough a call ajax (for purpose of example)
- Php Publish back to Redis
- Redis receive the event and trigger socket.io to broadcast the event

**Set up view:**

```
<input type="text" id="message">
<button id="sendMessage">Send alert</button>
```

**Client side Js**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000/');

socket.on('notification', function (data) {

    alert(data.message);
    console.log('message received');
});

// Ajax event
$(document).on('click','#sendMessage', function(){

    $.ajax({
      url: '/send/notification',
      method: 'POST',
      type: 'JSON',
      data: { message: $('#message').val() },
      success:function(data)
      {
        console.log('message sent');
      }
    })
});
```

**Php Server Side for Communicate to redis**

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$redis = new Predis\Client();
$redis->publish('notification',$message);
```

**NodeJs**

At this point on my `NodeJs` server I will go to listen for the **message** event in redis for then broadcast the event to sockets but here is the first issue I met.

```
var http = require('http');
var app  = http.createServer();
var io   = require('socket.io')(app);
var redis = require('redis');

app.listen(3000,'127.0.0.1',function(){
    console.log("listening:", app.address().port, app.address().address);
});

io.on('connection', function(client){
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();

    redisClient.subscribe('notification');

    redisClient.on("message",function(channel,data){

          // This line should broadcast to all the client except the sender
          socket.broadcast.emit(channel,JSON.parse(data));

          console.log(channel);
    });
});
```

### Issue

At this point where I `console.log()` the `channel` I can see on my terminal 5 logs "notification" Why 5?

When socket.io `broadcast` the event, it does that **5 times**, sending in this case **5** `alert()` to the `clients` and **4** to the `sender` instead of 1 for all clients a 0 for the sender.

The times are depending on how many users are connected I really don't understand what I missed, because it shouldn't be the right behaviour.

I already tried to put the creation of the `redisClient` and the subscription of a channel outside of the `io.on('connection')` with no luck, same result.

---

**Another Test**

if I `broadcast` the event on the connection of the socket like so:

```
io.on('connection', function(client)
{
     client.broadcast.emit('notification','hello');
});
```

It works correctly, so I think is redis problem. Any suggest will be really appreciated.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but it's not really clear to me why you use PHP at all. You could just call a NodeJS WebService to post the messages, and you'd get rid of one additional part of your development stack (unless you don't need PHP for other things)...

Answer (score 2):

You are having 5 clients connected, so the "connection" event is fired 5 times.
Thus there are 5 listeners for redis which all then broadcast.

There are two ways to do it correctly:

a) 1 listener per connection, only send the message to the connection

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();

    redisClient.subscribe('notification');

    redisClient.on("message",function(channel,data){

          // This line should broadcast to only the current connection
          socket.emit(channel,JSON.parse(data));

          console.log(channel);
    });
});
```

b) 1 global listener, broadcast to all clients

```
var redisClient = redis.createClient();

redisClient.subscribe('notification');

redisClient.on("message",function(channel,data){

   // This line should broadcast to all the client except the sender
   io.sockets.emit(channel,JSON.parse(data));

   console.log(channel);
});
```

I would prefer method b) as it only needs one redis connection.

Comment: Thanks a lots for your answer,I made same experiment on it. Using the method b) it emit to all the clients (even the sender) it shouldn't. if I use `broadcast` method instead it go mad sending 2 notifications each. 

On the method a) it does the same thing emit to all clients, but how you said having multiple connection.

How can I use the method b) with the `broadcast` method for send the event to all the clients except the sender?

I would like have a bit of chat with you if you don't mind here, will be really useful to me. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63024/nodejs-redis-php

Answer (score -1):

I have done same in one project.Only difference is I  publish notification from node.js but i did not get any issue.There is broadcast only open socket.